# How self join works

Tags: sql, self-join

I have a customer table:

```
ID  Name  Referred_id  
1   aaa
2   bbb   1
3   ccc   2
4   ddd   2
5   eee   4
```

I want to have a new column referred_name that should show who referred which customer based on referred_id, the output should be:

```
ID  Name  Referred_id  Referred_name
1   aaa
2   bbb   1               aaa
3   ccc   2               bbb
4   ddd   2               bbb
5   eee   4               ddd
```

Can someone please help me with the query

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Its resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.Name 'Referred_name' FROM Customer t1 LEFT JOIN Customer t2 ON t1.Referred_id = t2.ID
```

Comment: I am trying to join it with invoice table which has columns as ID - 101, biling_date - 01-01-2017, cust_id 2, I wrote the query as : (select c.id, i.billing_date, c.name, (select t2.name as referred_name from cust t1 left join cust t2 on t1.referred_id=t2.id) from cust1 c inner join invoice i on c.id=i_cust_id ) , its throwing error as scalar subquery produced more than one element, could you please help

Answer (score 2):

Try this syntax:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Name,
    t1.Referred_id,
    COALESCE(t2.Name, '') AS Referred_name
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.Referred_id = t2.ID
ORDER BY
    t1.ID;
```

### Demo

The join logic is most likely where you were having trouble.  The join condition above simply says to bring in the data for each referred ID corresponding to some other referrer ID in the same table.  Note that we use a left join here, because the first record was not referred by anybody, and we still want to include it.